# Разно-, равно- это приставки или корни с соединительной гласной?

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор, приставка

Существуют ли приставки разно-, равно- или это корни с соединительной гласной?

Comment: Напишите примеры, пожалуйста!

Comment: Равнобедренный, равносторонний, разносторонний, разноцветный, разнородный

Comment: Уберите во всех словах "равно" и "разно" - что получится?

Comment: Бедренная кость, к примеру

Comment: А если говорить про треугольник?

Comment: Какая-то ерунда

Answer (score 1):

**разный**
1. Неодинаковый, несходный в чем-нибудь, различный. *Разные мнения, вкусы. Разные способы.*
|| Иной, другой, не один и тот же. *Они живут в разных домах.*
2. Разнообразный, различный, многообразный.
3. Всякий, какой попало (разг., с оттенком пренебр.). *Накопилось много разного хлама.*
4. в знач. сущ. разное.
**разно...**
 ***Первая часть сложных слов***:
 1)  разноглубинный, разнокрылый, разномыслящий, разновеликий;
 2)  разновременный, разновысокий, разномасштабный;
 3)  разноголосый, разнокалиберный, разномастный, разнорабочий, разнотравье;
 4)  разнотолки.

**равный**
равная, равное; ра́вен, равна́, равно́.
1. Одинаковый, совершенно сходный, такой же (по величине, качеству, достоинству и т. п.). *Равные силы. Бревна равной толщины. Равные способности*.
|| Совершенно соответствующий по величине чему–н., равняющийся какой–н. величине (мат.).
2. Пользующийся такими же правами, имеющий такое же значение, занимающий такое же положение, как кто–н. другой. *«Словно с равными беседуя, он и с* *нищими учтив.»* Некрасов.
**равно...**
 ***Первая часть сложных слов***:
 1) равнобокий, равновесный, равнокрылый, равноправный;
 2) равновеликий, равновероятностный, равновозможный, равнодоступный, равнозначащий, равнопрочный.

***разнома́стный***
**Корень: -разн-;  интерфикс: -о-;  корень: -маст-**; суффикс: -н; окончание: -ый

***равнопра́вный***
**Корень: -равн-; интерфикс: -о-; корень: -прав-**; суффикс: -н; окончание: -ый

Интерфикс — служебная морфема, не имеющая собственного значения, но служащая для связи корней в сложных словах ( например, лоб-**о**-тряс ); простыми словами - соединительная гласная .

Answer (score 0):

Приставки русского языка делятся на три группы.

Приставки первой группы всегда пишутся одинаково, независимо от произношения. Это приставки: в- (во-), взо-, вы-, до-, за-, из- (изо-), к-, на-, над-, не-, недо-, о-, об- (обо-), от- (ото-), па-, пере-, по-, под- (подо-), пра-, пред- (предо-), про-, разо-, с- (со-), су-, у-.

Приставки второй группы — все приставки, оканчивающиеся на З и С (кроме с-): без- (бес-), вз- (вс-), воз- (вос-), из- (ис-), низ- (нис-), раз- (рас-), роз- (рос-), через- (черес-).

Приставки, относящиеся к третьей группе: пре- и при-. 
- Равно и - разно- в этом списке нет.  Значит, это корни.

Comment: Так нет здесь, допустим, приставки вне-. Список явно неполный

Comment: Для полноты списка.   Приставками являются также те, что восходят к наречным предлогам: вне-, меж-, возле-, сверх-, около-, противо-.
Внеклассный, межпланетный, сверхприбыльный, окололитературный, противоракетный.
Очень немного слов в русском языке имеют приставки па- (паводок, пасынок, падчерица), пра- (правнук, прадед), су- (сугроб, супесь, сумрак).

Answer (score 0):

Это не приставки в классическом понимании, приставки не несут собственной семантики, не имеют корня (отдельные исключения оговорены в грамматиках). Иногда говорят о префиксах (в широком смысле), но чаще всего эти компоненты характеризуют как "первую часть сложных слов". Сложные слова - имеющие два и более корня.

В отношении соединительной гласной. Скорее всего здесь её нет, буква "о" здесь принадлежит первому компоненту, это что-то вроде внутреннего суффикса (инфикса), принадлежащего только первому корню.